# How to know from which component is the child component called from?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using vuex for centeralized state management

I will try explaining my problem as easily understandable as possible.

I have two components **componentA** and **componentB**.

**componentB**

```
<template>
    <p>{{ value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                value: ''
            };
        },
        created(){
            if(called from component 1){
                this.value = 'called from component 1';
            }else if(called from component 2){
                this.value = 'called from component 2';
            }else if(called from component 3){
                this.value = 'called from component 3';
            }else{
                this.value = 'called from default component';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**componentB** is present inside **componentA** as follows:

```
<template>

    <componentB></componentB>

</template>

<script>
    // import for componentB.
    export default{
        components:{
            'componentB': componentB
        }
    }
</script>
```

This whole combined component i.e   **componentB** inside **componentA** considered as single component is reusable.

So I use this combined reuseable component in various other components as follows:

**component 1**

```
  <template>

    <componentA></componentA>

</template>
```

**component 2**

```
  <template>

    <componentA></componentA>

</template>
```

**component 3**

```
  <template>

    <componentA></componentA>

</template>
```

so my problem is how can I know from which component was `created()` lifecycle hook of **componentB** called so that I can execute the appropriate functionality.

- I can think of using props but I have to pass the prop two levels deep everytime
- or Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find parent component like this: `this.$parent`.

If you need to find parent 2 levels deep, request deeper parent: `this.$parent.$parent` (note, that root instance has no parent obviously).

Example for your question:

```js
Vue.component('component-b', {
  template: `<div>I'm component-b</div>`,
  mounted() {
    // log parent tag 2 levels up:
   console.log('called by: ', this.$parent.$parent.$vnode.tag)
  }
});

// calls B
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: `<div>I'm component-a
   <component-b></component-b>
   </div>`
});

// this is the top component, calls A
Vue.component('component-top', {
  template: `<div><component-a></component-a></div>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component-top></component-top>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted but in docs API (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent) there is a warning saying: using so can serve as an escape hatch. What is the meaning of that?Using your example said if I console log the parents I am getting the name in the format "vue-component-<number>-componentname", for eg.: vue-component-3-mycomponentname. My question is the number remains constant or does will it change?..Asking all this because I did'nt undertand what the waring meant. Thank you

Comment: @user7814783 The warning means you really shouldn't use `$parent` unless you *have* to. Typically you should communicate between components using props and events.

Comment: @BertEvans in my case is it better to use props or $parent

Comment: Well, Vue team warns not to manipulate parent-child nodes directly, but use props-events communication instead. There's nothing wrong if you for some reason want to `read` a tag name (not to `set` namely). About numbers: AFAIK these numbers are defined `once` for global components, I'm not sure about nested components defined locally (needs some testing to find out). Anyway, you can use `String.prototype.endsWith` in order to substract a component tag from the output.

Comment: @user7814783 What is the real use case? Things are so generic here it's difficult to imagine a real world scenario.

Comment: @BertEvans the code i provided is the usecase....if i had to use props i have to pass it two levels deep.

Comment: @user7814783 what about `event bus`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: @user7814783 You're probably not writing componentA and componentB; you have some real-world scenario. What are the real components? What are you trying to do? If componentB is *always* in componentA, does it need to be a component? That's what I mean, It's difficult to answer any questions about architecture when there's no information about what you are really doing. In a case where componentA and componentB are *always* used together, `$parent` may be fine, but `$parent.$parent` would imply all three components are always used together. And in that case, they're not really re-usable.